# An eye in a blue face / Saw an eye in a green face

Tags: riddle

Another riddle (from *The Hobbit*):

> An eye in a blue face,
> Saw an eye in a green face.
> That eye is like to this eye,
> said the first eye,
> But in low place not in high place.

What are the faces and eyes in this riddle?

Comment: This riddle appeared in _The Hobbit_, when Bilbo was in Gollum's caverns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is [easily found by searching](https://www.riddles.com/872):

> The sun shining down on a daisy

Details:

> > An eye in a blue face,
>
> The sun (eye) in the sky (blue face)
>
> > Saw an eye in a green face.
>
> A daisy (eye) in the grass (green face)
>
> > That eye is like to this eye,
> >  said the first eye,
>
> Both "eye"s are yellow.
>
> > But in low place not in high place.
>
> The daisy is close to the ground while the sun is high in the sky